# encode url using htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I am trying to convert

```
www.domain.com/tag/c++  --> www.domain.com/index.php?qa=tag&qa_1=c++
```

I use this code :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$ /index.php?qa=$1&qa_1=$2 [R=301,L]
```

But It redirect page to c tag because for working properly It must convert it to %2B%2B first

It also redirect this page wrong too :

```
www.domain.com/tag/c%2B%2B
```

I am using this code for redirect user pages too and they have some characters like / space and ...

What is the best way for doing this stuffs with `htaccess` ?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b

Comment: `&qa_1=c++` would mean that `qa_l = 'c  '`.

Comment: @Emissary I tried it but it convert it to c%252B%252‌B I want c%2B%2B

Comment: @hjpotter92 I know that's why I asked this question any way :)

Comment: @Emissary And also It corrupt urf8 characters too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the [NE](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne) flag should do it. It will stop special characters from being encoded.

> By default, special characters, such as & and ?, for example, will be
>   converted to their hexcode equivalent. Using the [NE] flag prevents
>   that from happening.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$ /index.php?qa=$1&qa_1=$2 [R=301,L,NE]
```

it should allow you visit `www.domain.com/tag/c++` <- that url and get redirected to `www.domain.com/index.php?qa=tag&qa_1=c++`